# "Look for this sign in store" – is it correct?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, marketing

I was wondering whether a sentence like this "Look for this sign in store" is correct. The sign in question is a wobbler attached to products in a store that includes a QR code and a discount code.

One other option I have seen online is "Look for this sign in-store". Alternatively, "look for this sign in store**s**" is also a possibility.

What are your thoughts? Is any of the options correct and natural for native speakers?

Thank you

Comment: Is the promotion only in stores belonging to one retail chain or is it available across many chains and independent operators? The answer may depend on this context.

Comment: "Look for this sign in-store." (I'm adding the full stop to faithfully show a legitimate sentence, though pedants would claim some rule or other says it should be replaced by at most a comma as I'm continuing my matrix sentence) is quite correct. The relevant adverb / adjective is the hyphenated _in-store_. But it looks rather clumsy, and I'm pretty sure that an open version (when used adverbially) will become standard quite soon. The use of 'in stores' is of course ...

Comment: incontestably 'correct', but far less punchy. If 'Beanz Meanz Heinz' has survived the prescriptive backlash for 50 years, I don't think this is worth getting bothered about.

Comment: I'm not sure why we are proofreading someone else's marketing copy. That is not the job of a linguist. Indeed it is not a job at all if we don't get paid.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I'd argue it's a case for grammatical consideration – in store vs. in-store and the proper use of phrases in marketing / commercial / natural usage. By no means am I asking you to review a "marketing copy", I am asking whether the phrasing is correct, and if not, how to improve it. Sorry for adding background to the question...